# PyQGIS: Editable Combobox for Value Map widget isses

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am having issues with an editable combo box in QGIS 2.4. The edit widget is set to Value Map with an uploaded CSV. However, if a new values (not included in the key value pair list) is added, the attribute value is not saved, thus defeating the purpose of the editable combo box.

Currently, I have it set editable like this in my python form (set under python init in layer properties).

```
Attributefield.setEditable(True)
```

I saw a checkbox "Editable" option for value map as well, but nothing happens when it is checked (combo box is not editable).

My original goals are mentioned in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107334/qgis-2-4-adding-feature-with-setlineedit-data-not-saving-to-database), using setLineEdit PyQt method. But I decided to try this editable combo box option, which still does not work.

Comment: Do you want to fire the signal or respond to it? Can you give a hint on what you're trying to do when the edits are saved?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I just updated my question

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a quandary. You might have to ask the respondent program to wait a predefined interval and then do the export.

Comment: According to the docs http://qgis.org/api/2.4/classQgsVectorLayer.html the editingStopped signal is fired *after* the edits are saved and the beforeCommitChanges is fired *before* the edits are saved. When you respond to editingStopped the attributes should already be updated... perhaps the problem is elsewhere, perhaps with the export itself, how do you achive this? May I suggest a test routine to report the value for each event then modify an attribute and save edits and compare the two values.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I've been testing the unique values using python sets and printing them in a QMessageBox. Thanks for the info on editingStopped. I'll update my question as soon as I find out what's actually the problem, then.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I now found the real and very unrelated reason for my problem. So sorry.

Comment: Well, that's good news. No need to be sorry. Is it worth sharing where the problem actually is?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson My question has been completely modified. It's an editable combo box issue...very closely related to an old problem of mine that I got working in QGIS 2.0 and has come back in QGIS 2.4.